# Creating domain Storage Buckets

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-deployment-manager

```
message: '{"ResourceType":"storage.v1.bucket","ResourceErrorCode":"403","ResourceErrorMessage":{"code":403,"errors":[{"domain":"global","message":"The
    bucket you tried to create requires domain ownership verification.","reason":"forbidden"}],"message":"The
    bucket you tried to create requires domain ownership verification.","statusMessage":"Forbidden","requestPath":"https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b","httpMethod":"POST","suggestion":"Consider
    granting permissions to 1058303916595@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com"}}'
```

Above is the message when I tried to create storagebuckets via Deployment Manager. I already tried adding `1058303916595@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com` to the Verified owners of that domain on the Google Search Console but still no luck

Answer (score -1):

To create a Storage Bucket with domain name, **your account** should be a verified owner of the domain, not the **cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com**. Additional information can be found in  [Domain-Named Bucket Verification](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/domain-name-verification?hl=en_US&_ga=2.145653108.-1930564147.1543924922&_gac=1.169987604.1550578143.EAIaIQobChMIw76f6tzH4AIVxITVCh1NDAkpEAAYASAAEgIuIPD_BwE) documentation.

You have to login to your domain name provider with the same account that you use to login to the Google Cloud Console. Then request a new domain name, go to Google Cloud Console App Engine page. Go to Settings and then click on `Custom domains` and then `Add a custom domain`. After adding the domain name there and verifying it, you will be able to create a bucket name using that domain as name. But make sure to do so with the same account that the domain was verified with.

Comment: I meant creating w/ the use of Cloud Deployment Manager. I can create via Google Cloud Console but what I want is via Cloud Deployment Manager. I can not find anything in their documentation regarding this

Comment: For deployment you can find examples created by Google in [Deployment Manager Examples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples). You can test these [deploymentmanager-samples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/tree/master/google/resource-snippets/storage-v1) directly from Cloud Shell. However the account that is going to be specified in the `.jinja` file, should be the same account that verified the ownership of the domain. Also those files should be deployed in Cloud Shell running from that account.

Comment: Sorry but there is none in there. Unless you can specifically point and provide a solution yourself and not just pointing out something